# $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N, \forall n > N : \\
F(x- \epsilon) < F_n(x) < F(x+ \epsilon) \implies F_n(x) \rightarrow F(x) $

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

F is a distribution.

Is this statement true? It seems obvious but I m bot sure how to prove it.

Sorry if this is really obvious, let s pretend i m beginning in maths ^^'

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N, \forall n > N : \\
F(x- \epsilon) < F_n(x)  < F(x+ \epsilon) \implies F_n(x) \rightarrow F(x) $$

Comment: If it was for all $x$, for all $\epsilon$, that $F(x)-\epsilon<F_n(x)<F(x)+\epsilon$ holds for $n$ large enough then this would be the definition of $F_n$ converging pointwise to $F$.

Comment: It is. But I have another definition for pointwise convergence. It is : $\abs( F_n(x) - F(x)) < \epsilon$ forall epsilon there exists a n big enough

Comment: $|F_n(x)-F(x)|<\epsilon$ if and only if $-\epsilon<F_n(x)-F(x)<\epsilon$. You should review the basics of absolute value.

Comment: Well please take a look at my post, the epsilons are inside the function not outside. I don't know what you mean

Comment: I realize that. It was just a comment. But be sure our definitions of pointwise convergence are *trivially equivalent*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For said $x$, it holds $$\sup_{y<x} F(y)\le \liminf_{n\to \infty} F_n(x)\le \limsup_{n\to\infty} F_n(x)\le \inf_{y>x}F(y)=F(x)$$

Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty} F_n(x)$ exist and it is equal to $F(x)$ under the additional assumption that $F$ is continuous at $x$.

It may not be the case for points where $F$ is discontinuous. For instance, consider \begin{align}F(x)&=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x<0\\ 1&\text{if }x\ge 0\end{cases}\\ F_n(x)&=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x\le 0\\ x^{1/n}&\text{if }0<x< 1\\ 1&\text{if }x\ge 1\end{cases}\end{align}
For which $F_n(0)\not\to F(0)$.

Comment: Please, what is the link between y and n and where are epsilons appearing? I m really confused. I m searching for something really precise to be sure of what I m writing

Answer (score 1):

What if $F$ is the step function defined by $F(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $F(x)=1$ for $x\geq0$, while $F_n(x)$ is identical with $F(x)$ except that $F(0)=\frac12$? Then your assumption holds for $x=0$ but your conclusion doesn't. (A minor modification, to make $F$ and the $F_n$'s nowhere constant but still having a jump at $0$, can make the assumption to hold for all $x$ while the conclusion still fails at $x=0$.)